# How to apply regex to split columns in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a column that looks the strings look like this:

```
Accommodation and food services [72]
Wholesale trade [41]
Trade [41-45N]
```

The string inside the brackets doesn't have a pattern, I want to separate it in two columns, one with the industry name and the other with the industry id (info inside brackets). I tried many ways, but nothing worked. Thanks in advance.

```
[output] columnA:                                  columnB:
         Accommodation and food services           [72]
         Wholesale trade                           [41]
         Trade                                     [41-45N]
```

Comment: Can you share some of your attempts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do `rsplit`

```
newdf=df['col'].str.rsplit(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
pat = '^(.*) (\[.*\])$'
df['strCol'].str.extract(pat)
```